# Change AppBarButtoon Background color

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

in C# Windows Phone 8.1, I create an AppBarButton with this XAML code:

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="btnMore" Icon="More" Foreground="White"  IsEnabled="False" Label="More" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Click="AppBarButton_Click" />
```

in the dark theme of the phone everything is fine:

[image]

but in the LIGHT theme, backcolor and font color are black:

[image]

I tried to set a Background and BorderBrush for this problem but nothing changes, still in Light Theme passage and circle is black (even when the button is enabled)

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="btnMore"  Icon="More" Foreground="White"  IsEnabled="False" Label="More" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Click="AppBarButton_Click" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" />
```

how do I solve this?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a7731a4-e557-47b4-94eb-4c46209d0dfe/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-available-appbar-icon-including-the-circle-enclosing-the-icon-itself?forum=w81prevwCsharp), however, it is a little over complicated, involves  retemplating the AppBarButton.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `RequestedTheme="Dark"` on your `AppBarButton` will force it to be white irregardless of the chosen theme.

---

Why are you setting `Foreground="White"` on the app bar button? The app bar button will automatically adjust its colors correctly depending on the light/dark theme chosen. It looks as if you have forced the page background color to black and the text foreground color to white, so when the app bar button changes its colors, it doesn't match the background anymore. If you want to force your app to use the dark theme only, then set `RequestedTheme="Dark"` on any of your `Application`, `Page`, or even `AppBarButton` (depending on what scope you want to affect).

Comment: Any hard-coded colour is a red-flag for problems with theming. Also test with high contrast modes. If you need custom colours beyond picking the RequestedTheme put them in a ThemeDictionary so you can provide appropriate colours for different themes. For high contrast modes you'll usually want to default to a system colour.

Answer (score 0):

Your button is most likely inside a CommandBar.
Go to the CommandBar and set its Foreground to whatever color you like.
This should solve your problem. It has worked for me.

Comment: The AppBar is system UI and doesn't allow control of the individual button colours. If RMT's button were in an app bar the button's Foreground colour would be ignored and this problem wouldn't occur.